# Typescript parameters of overloaded functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am doing something like the following:

```
import React from "react";

interface BaseFormValue {
  name: string;
}

export interface NewFormValue extends BaseFormValue {
  email: string;
}

export interface ExistingFormValue extends BaseFormValue {}

export type FormValue = NewFormValue | ExistingFormValue;

export type existingFormSetter = (
  setter: (prev: ExistingFormValue) => ExistingFormValue
) => void;

export type newFormSetter = (
  setter: (prev: NewFormValue) => NewFormValue
) => void;

export type formSetter = existingFormSetter & newFormSetter;

let newFormState: NewFormValue = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
};

const newFormSetter: newFormSetter = (setter) => {
  newFormState = setter(newFormState);
};

type NewFormProps = {
  type: "new";
  value: NewFormValue;
  onChange: newFormSetter;
};

type ExistingFormProps = {
  type: "existing";
  value: ExistingFormValue;
  onChange: existingFormSetter;
};

type FormProps = NewFormProps | ExistingFormProps;

const MyComponent: React.FC<FormProps> = (formProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={formProps.value.name}
        onChange={({ target: { value: input } }) => {
          // Doesn't work
          formProps.onChange((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: input }));

          // Works
          switch (formProps.type) {
            case "existing":
              formProps.onChange((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: input }));
              break;
            case "new":
              formProps.onChange((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: input }));
              break;
          }
        }}
      />
      {formProps.type === "new" && (
        <input
          value={formProps.value.email}
          onChange={({ target: { value: input } }) => {
            formProps.onChange((prev) => ({ ...prev, email: input }));
          }}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

If I don't surround formProps.onChange call with an if/switch statement I get the error:

> Parameter 'prev' implicitly has an 'any' type.

even if the switch does the same thing in both cases.

=================================================================================================================================

Answer (score 1):

Your `formProps.onChange` is expecting *either* a function that takes `NewFormValue` and return `NewFormValue` *or* a function that takes `ExistingFormValue` and returns `ExistingFormValue`.  You can't make use of that union unless you know which one you are dealing with, which is why your `switch` example works.

One thing that you can do is to define your update function as a generic that returns the same type as its argument.  That generic signature would be assignable to both types in the union.

```
onChange={({ target: { value: input } }) => {
  const callback = <T extends BaseFormValue>(prev: T): T => ({...prev, name: input })
  formProps.onChange(callback);
}}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mq8ERN)